# ComponentLookupException in Maven project

Tags: java, maven, plugins, netbeans, war

> Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) on
> project Gestion_pfe: Execution default-war of goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war failed: Unable to
> load the mojo 'war' in the plugin
> 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1' due to an API
> incompatibility:
> org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException:
> Cannot access defaults field of Properties

I haven't done anything yet in the code. I just try to run the project before I start coding.

Comment: Show us the `pom.xml`

Comment: Please follow the guidelines in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that you can improve your question.